# posgresql : We have data in this A format and need to change like B format how can i do this one?

Tags: postgresql

We have data in this A format and need to change like B format how can I do this one?

Format A:

```
S.N0      ATTRIBUTE1
  1       Last_contact_date
  2       20200512335566 --yyyymmddhhmmss
```

Format B:

```
S.NO      ATTRIBUTE1
  1       Last_contact_date
  2       20200512 --YYYYMMDD
```

Comment: Are those strings?

Comment: `left(attribute1, 8)`?

Comment: that's not valid datetime value ,  we don't have 33 as hour , the same with seconds

Comment: yes above one is example  (this is exact 20200512000000)... wrote  query like substring("attribute2",1,8) as attribute2 but it's changing  last contact_date as last_con .... need help on this without effecting 1st row how we can achieve this ?

Comment: Are you trying to update the table? Then just add a `WHERE` clause. Or are you trying to do this in a `SELECT` query? Then you'll need a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

if you want date format , you can use 'to_date` function:

```
select to_date('20200512335566', 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS')
```

however seems like the value is not valid, (33 as hour and 66 as second)

Comment: yes  said in example (this is exact 20200512000000)... i wrote  like substring("attribute2",1,8) as attribute2 but it's changing  last contact_date as last_con .... need help on this without effecting 1st row how we can achieve this ?